# order users with drag'n'drop?

Tags: users, order

There are many plugins out there that let you order Pages and/or Posts with drag and drop.

Is there something similar to order users?

Or if not, is it possible to create a plugin for that (i.e. are there sufficient filters, actions etc. in place?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain in detail why do you need to order users? What's the purpose it will serve for you?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam All the users on my site are also authors and I'd like to have them listed on a special page. And I'd like to be able to manually sort them. I hope that explanation might help... somehow...

Comment: Even if we can't close the question right now: It's off topic as it's a plugin recommendation. Please edit it to bring it on topic. The [help] might be of help to achieve that.

Comment: The "special page" listing authors you are talking about: are you looking for a frontend, public page that lists the authors?  How many authors do you have?

Comment: if you want to use the shopping cart of drag and drop  you can use ecwid  for this its third party integration and have drag and drop facilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no such plugin...

So I created my own: https://github.com/cek125i/simple-user-ordering
(~300 php lines, too long to post here)

Influenced a lot by "Simple Page Ordering" plugin, but created from scratch.

The lousy truth about this problem is that there seems to be no built-in way to sort users by meta-value. Luckily I have only 10-20 users so hopefully it won't be too performance-expensive to sort them manually after fetching (that means one additional query per user to fetch meta value).

Answer (score 5):

Quite a specific feature, never seen any plugin. But it's a matter of taking a drag'n'drop plugin and adapting it.

Here, a stripped and adapted version of [My Link Order](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-link-order/tags/3.5/mylinkorder.php).
Description and **to-do**:

- A new submenu is created in Users, *My Users Order*.
- In the plugin page, execute the function `orderUsers()` in your browser console, you'll see the current order as an array. Drag and drop and execute again, the array shows the new order.
- You'll have to use the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) or create your [AJAX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) code to deal with saving the order as User Meta data.
- The styles and scripts printed within the submenu callback should go in their own CSS and JS files, and enqueued accordingly.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: My Users Order */

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myuserorder_menu' );

function myuserorder_menu()
{    
    $page = add_users_page(
        __( 'My Users Order', 'myuserorder' ), 
        __( 'My Users Order', 'myuserorder' ), 
        'manage_links', 
        'myuserorder', 
        'myuserorder'
    );
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$page", 'myuserorder_js_libs' );
}

function myuserorder_js_libs() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable', false, array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery' ) );
}

function myuserorder()
{
    ?>
    <div class='wrap'>
        <form name="frmMyUserOrder" method="post" action="">
            <h2><?php _e('My Users Order', 'myuserorder') ?></h2>   
            <ul id="myUserOrderList">
            <?php
            $results = get_users();
            foreach( $results as $user )
                echo "<li id='{$user->data->ID}' class='lineitem'>" . $user->data->display_name . "</li>";
            ?>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
        #myUserOrderList {
            width: 90%; 
            border:1px solid #B2B2B2; 
            margin:10px 10px 10px 0px;
            padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
            list-style:none;
            background-color:#fff;
            -moz-border-radius:3px;
            -webkit-border-radius:3px;
        }
        li.lineitem {
            border:1px solid #B2B2B2;
            -moz-border-radius:3px;
            -webkit-border-radius:3px;
            background-color:#F1F1F1;
            color:#000;
            cursor:move;
            font-size:13px;
            margin-top:5px;
            margin-bottom:5px;
            padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
            height:1.5em;
            line-height:1.5em;
        }       
        .sortable-placeholder{ 
            border:1px dashed #B2B2B2;
            margin-top:5px;
            margin-bottom:5px; 
            padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
            height:1.5em;
            line-height:1.5em;  
        }
    </style>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function orderUsers() 
        {
            var newOrder = jQuery("#myUserOrderList").sortable("toArray");
            console.log( newOrder );
        }
        function myuserorderaddloadevent()
        {
            jQuery("#myUserOrderList").sortable({ 
                placeholder: "sortable-placeholder", 
                revert: false,
                tolerance: "pointer" 
            });
        };
        addLoadEvent( myuserorderaddloadevent );
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Sweet concept - straight forward. +1